# Is there any offline circuit simulator software that can simulate a noisy power supply?

Tags: power-supply, noise, simulation, ripple

I have been using Circuit Wizard (Its the only offline program that I can find!). Unfortunately, it is really basic, and I have outgrown it.

I need to simulate a 5V circuit with a noisy power supply, with a lot of ripple/noise (anything from 0.1v to 1v). I am an electronics novice, and I have tried all sorts of things, like these: [image: Crazy Attempt 1] [image: Crazy Attempt 2]  [image: Crazy Attempt 3]

And none of them work properly. I was wondering:

1. Is there a way to make this work at all?
2. Is there a good offline circuit simulator (as I do not always have internet access) that is easy to use, and can simulate noisy power supplies?

EDIT: I do not mind if the programs are freeware or paid.

Comment: Yes : Simulate your noise source in series with the ideal source. Voltage sources in series add. (Ideal) voltage sources in parallel are a logical contradiction.

Comment: BTW, if you use Windows you might want to look at LTSpice for a free (as in beer) simulator with a good-sized user community.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to put your noise source in series with the ideal source:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUTVZt.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Voltage sources in series add. (Ideal) voltage sources in parallel are a logical contradiction.